# What are the features of WS_POPUP?

Tags: winapi

What does WS_POPUP imply exactly? It is not stated on MS Docs, as opposed to some other styles:

WS_OVERLAPPED - "An overlapped window has a title bar and a border."

WS_SYSMENU - "The window has a window menu on its title bar."

And so on. But the WS_POPUP style is just described as creating a pop-up window.
I couldn't find much information about this on the internet.

**So, what does a WS_POPUP window usually look like, and how can we describe its distinctive features?**

(I recently used WS_POPUP style to overcome a strange rendering behavior of a layered window, and I have no idea how and why that worked. So I hope this will help me understand that. If you're interested, check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67689087/correct-way-to-handle-and-redraw-a-layered-window-with-a-bitmap) post of mine)

Comment: [Pop-up Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/window-features#pop-up-windows).